# Where do I find the comment IP address?

Tags: 8, comments

I am searching for comments ip address in D8 and I can't find where they are located in database. In D7 it was easy to find.

Is there a chance that D8 is not storing the commenters ip address? If it is not, how can I store it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP addresses are stored in the `hostname` field of the comment entity (which you'd usually find in the `comment_field_data` table).

This functionality is disabled by default, though (see [Stop logging comment IP addresses by default](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2828793)). To enable it, it looks like you need to set the config manually, e.g.

```
 \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('comment.settings')
   ->set('log_ip_addresses', TRUE)
   ->save(TRUE);
```

After running that, IP addresses will start being logged in the `hostname` field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There are 12k comments in my blog so far. If I add in comment.install I guess that I would have to reinstall comment module and lose all comments? Or I can add it in some other place?

Comment: @isin – Of course you don't add any custom code to a core or contrib module. You don't reinstall comments. You can execute the code from this answers from a custom module's hook_update_N or from the command line via `drush ev "\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('comment.settings')->set('log_ip_addresses', TRUE)->save(TRUE);"`.

Comment: Thank you Clive for the solution and leymannx for pointing out how to use the code. Started now a new installation and tried by using the drush ev... and it worked.